# Erro ao gerar PDF no CakePHP através do FPDF

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, fpdf

Estou reescrevendo um sistema legado da empresa em que trabalho (usando CakePHP para isso) e ele gera alguns relatórios em PDF usando FPDF. No entanto, no CakePHP não consigo gerar qualquer PDF.

Segue o código

### Action

```
function pdf ($id = null) {
    App::import('Vendor', 'Fpdf', array('file' => 'fpdf/fpdf.php'));
    $this->layout = 'pdf';         
    $this->set('fpdf', new FPDF('P','mm','A4'));

    $mensagem = is_null($id) ? "Nenhum ID fornecido" : "ID: $id";
    $this->set('data', $mensagem);

    $this->response->type('pdf'); 
    $this->render('pdf');
}
```

### View

```
$fpdf->AddPage(); 
$fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16); 
$fpdf->Cell(40,10, $data); 
$fpdf->Output();
```

Não aparece nenhum erro, apenas o plugin de PDF do Chrome e fica escrito "carregando" mas nunca carrega.

Não é nenhum problema no servidor pois, no mesmo servidor de testes, tem um espelho do sistema antigo funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Qual é o erro gerado?

Comment: Nenhum, aparece o plugin de pdf do chrome e fica apenas carregando, se eu dou ctrl+s vem um documento vazio. Obrigado pelo toque

Comment: Pode ser demora pra carregar e/ou construir o PDF? Tem como você fazer debugging pra ver como a execução ocorre?

Comment: Você está chamando `$fpdf->Output()` na sua view?

Comment: Gostaria de ver o código da View também para poder tentar reproduzir o problema

Comment: @mutley não é demora, ele fica assim pra sempre. Também tentei usar o debug mas não saiu nada.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro estou

Comment: @ErlonCharles  

    `$fpdf->AddPage();`
    `$fpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);`
    `$fpdf->Cell(40,10, $data);`
    `$fpdf->Output();`

Comment: Está retornado um documento pdf _válido_ mas vazio ou um arquivo vazio?

Comment: @AndréRibeiro vem um arquivo vazio.

Comment: @rafaslide tente adicionar um `error_reporting(E_ALL)` no início da sua action só pra ver se o `FPDF` gera algum erro que não está sendo mostrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava no Layout (pdf) que eu estava usando, no final mesmo estava tudo certo com a action e a view, o que faltava era uma parte do código. Precisava dar echo no conteudo através da variável `$content_for_layout;` e eu não tinha me atentado a isto.

Obrigado a todos pelo apoio.

Answer (score 1):

Existe a possibilidade de migrar para o HtmlToPDF? Se sim, faça essa migração. Também tive diversos problemas com o FPDF que só consegui resolver com a migração.

No mais, abra as ferramentas de desenvolvimento do Chrome (CTRL+J) e na aba Rede (ou Network), verifique o que está sendo carregado ao tentar gerar o pdf.